# How to navigate from one page to other page in the page constructor in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation

i am using xamarin forms and i have a scenario where i have 3 pages(content pages) . 
In page1 on the click of a button i need to goto page2. and in the the page2 check a flag to decide whether to stay in page2 or redirect to page3. i am trying to do this logic in page 2 constructor and my NavigationStack is coming up as empty. Please suggest.

Page2 constructor:

```
public Page2()
{
  InitializeComponent();
   If(check==true)
   {    
     Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page3());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            viewModel.InitializeData();
        }
```

and in intialize data write the if condition

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `PushAsync` method to not lose the previous stack.. What u're doing is just keeping the stack with minimal size (1 page). Try this code, but you have to `await` it, so you 're better not doing it the constructor

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.NavigationPage.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new Page3()));
```

Comment: i did not want to maintain multiple pages in stack as my pages heavy on data. i just came across OnApearing event. got resolved using that.